# How to get the field name to check if field should include quotes or not?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I need to add quotes to some fields. The field type should not considered because some strings should have quotes and others not.

So I added the following configuration:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {
    ShouldQuote = args =>
    {
        var b = quoted.Contains(args.Field);
        return b;
    }
};
```

The `quoted` variable is a list of field names that need quotes.

But `args.Field` is not the field name but the field value. Is there a way to check what the field name is at this stage or maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `args.Row.HeaderRecord` along with `args.Row.Index` to determine the header name of the field.  If you also want the actual header name quoted, you will have to check `args.field` since the `HeaderRecord` will not have been populated at that point.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var quoted = new List<string> { "Id" };
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        ShouldQuote = args =>
        {
            if (args.Row.HeaderRecord != null)
            {
                return quoted.Contains(args.Row.HeaderRecord[args.Row.Index]);
            }
            
            if (args.Row.Row == 1)
            {
                return quoted.Contains(args.Field);
            }
            
            return false;
        }
    };

    var records = new List<Foo>{
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
        new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "Name2" }
    };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, config))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```